Unable to draw contours on the image
I am trying to draw contours on an image, but I am unable to see the contours on the output image. Here's what I'm doing in my code:

Read the input image.
Convert it to grayscale.
Apply a binary threshold.
Use findContours to detect contours.
Draw the contours on the original image.

I wrote the logic in the below snippet
fn extract_corners(images_path: &str) {
    let images = fs::read_dir(images_path).unwrap();

    for (i, image) in images.enumerate() {
        let image_path = image.unwrap().path();

        let im = imread(image_path.to_str().unwrap(), IMREAD_COLOR).unwrap();
        highgui::imshow("Original Image", &im).unwrap();

        let mut gray = Mat::default();
        cvt_color(&im, &mut gray, imgproc::COLOR_BGR2GRAY, 0).unwrap();
        highgui::imshow("Grayscale Image", &gray).unwrap();

        let mut thresh = Mat::default();
        threshold(&gray, &mut thresh, 150.0, 255.0, THRESH_BINARY).unwrap();
        highgui::imshow("Binary Image", &thresh).unwrap();
        let mut contours = VectorOfMat::new();
        let mut hierarchy = Mat::default();
        find_contours(
            &thresh,
            &mut contours,
            RETR_EXTERNAL,
            CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,
            Point::new(0, 0),
        ).unwrap();

        println!("Number of contours found: {}", contours.len());

        let mut output_image = im.clone();
        draw_contours(
            &mut output_image,
            &contours,
            -1, // Draw all contours
            Scalar::new(0.0, 255.0, 0.0, 0.0), // Green color
            3,                                 // Thickness
            imgproc::LINE_8,
            &mut hierarchy,
            0,
            Point::new(0, 0),
        ).unwrap();

        highgui::imshow(&format!("Contours Image {}", i), &output_image).unwrap();

        highgui::wait_key(0).unwrap();
    }
}

Here’s the relevant section of my code:
[Link to source code](https://github.com/anchalshivank/Jinzougan/blob/7800f9254cfc144d9ebc863b5943340670772a60/src/main.rs#L189)
I tested this on the following images:

Input Image 1:


Input Image 2:



However, the output image does not display any contours:

I expect to see the contours drawn in green on the images, but nothing appears.
Is there an issue with my preprocessing steps or the way I’m drawing the contours?
Thank you!
I attempted to preprocess the image by first converting it to grayscale, then applying a threshold, and finally detecting contours. I also checked the number of contours with a length greater than zero. However, the contours are not being drawn.

[mre] required. debug your code. find out which parts cause the issue, and which parts don't. reduce the code. swap parts of it for dummy code.

You probably shouldn't be drawing contours with a transparent color if you want to see them
